# setState is assigning the function not the value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to setState by accessing prev value. But setState makes data a function not the returned value. I do not want to pass data to openElements function or access it by any different way which causes a re-render in my component any time data change.

Here is current code:

```
const openElements = ({ childsIds, i, setData, isItemChildClick }: OpenElementsFunc) => {
  setData((prev: Items) => {
    const tempData = [...prev];
    tempData[i] = { ...tempData[i], isOpen: isItemChildClick ? tempData[i].isOpen : true };
    childsIds.map((el) => {
      const i = prev.findIndex((elm) => elm.id === el);
      if (i !== -1) tempData[i] = { ...tempData[i], isShown: true };
    });
    return tempData;
  });
};
```

When I `console.log` the data it gives me this:

```
prev => {
    const tempData = [...prev];
    tempData[i] = {
      ...tempData[i],
      isOpen: isItemChildClick ? tempData[i].isOpen : true
    };
    childsIds.map(el => {
      const i = prev.fi…
```

Comment: from your question, I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve, you want to have previous state or you want to update state based on the previous state?

Comment: I want to update state based on previous state

Comment: What are you trying to `console.log`?  Also unrelated but seems like `forEach` might be better than `map` for your use since `map` returns an array which you do not use.